# How to keep a text box responsive on top of image?

Tags: css

I have an image, that unfortunately cannot be used as a background image, with a text box on top of it. It works but it's not responsive, using bootstrap 4. When I get to smaller screen size the text box out grows beyond the image.

At initial size it's fine but once you shrink the page then the text box just shoots out. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid something-container">
<div class="row">
<img class="img-responsive something-img" src="http://placehold.it/900x100"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row something-front d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-8 something-text text-center">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <p>Here are some words but typically a lot more are present here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.something-container{
 position:relative;
 text-align: center;
}
.something-img{
width: 100%;
}
.something-text{
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 color: white;
 p {
   line-height: 2em;
   padding-left: 10px;
 }
 h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 550;
    padding-top: 20px;
 }
}
```

I created a CodePen to show it: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/jakewayne/pen/aqeNgK)

How do I get that text box to remain within the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap both your image and your text in a wrapper div like `.image-wrapper` like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid something-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row something-front d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
          <img class="img-responsive something-img" src="http://placehold.it/900x100" />
          <div class="col-sm-8 something-text text-center">
            <h1>Header</h1>
            <p>Here are some words but typically a lot more are present here.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.something-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.something-text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: white;
  height: 90%;
}
```

This gives the job of positioning to a parent element and you can style the image and text independently, while keeping the box dimensions the same/responsive. The font size will have to change as the size increases/shrinks to keep it all in the box, but the text will be centered with the image.

Comment: @Jake Did this answer your question?